# Changing HTML Content to Json Content

Tags: jquery, html, json, ajax

I have a few navigation buttons and a content area for contents.
I couldn't pull the data from.JSON file to my HTML content area without refreshing the whole page. 
I just want to update my content area when I click on certain navigation buttons

I tried using AJAX but it didn't work. As my knowledge to JSON and AJAX is not much and I did some searches on how could I do it but it just couldn't get the contents area to be updated.

HTML File

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"><head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" /><title>A simple AJAX website with jQuery</title>

<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="demo.css" />
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.3.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="script.js"></script>
</head>




<body>
<div id="rounded">
<img src="img/top_bg.gif" alt="top" />
<div id="main" class="container">
<h1>A simple AJAX driven jQuery website</h1>
<h2>Because simpler is better</h2>
<ul id="navigation">
<li><a href="#page_1">Page 1</a></li>
<li><a href="#page_2">Page 2</a></li>
<li><a href="#page_3">Page 3</a></li>
<li><a href="#page_4">Page 4</a></li>
<li><a href="#products">Products</a></li>

<li><img id="loading" src="img/ajax_load.gif" alt="loading" /></li>
<br><br><br>
<li id="des1"><a href="#mushroom">Mushroom</a></li>
<li id="des2"><a href="#potato">Potato</a></li>
<li id="des3"><a href="#carrot">Carrot</a></li>
<li id="des4"><a href="#tomato">Tomato</a></li>
</ul>
<div class="clear"></div>
<div id="dvProdList"> </div>
<div class="clear"></div>
<div id="pageContent"> Hello, this is a demo for The Rich
Internet Application Case Study<a href="http://www.lithan.com" target="_blank">Lithan</a>. To test it,
click some of the buttons above. Have a nice stay!</div>
</div>


<div class="clear"></div>
<img src="img/bottom_bg.gif" alt="bottom" /></div>
<div class="demo" align="center">
this is a <a href="http://lithan.com/" target="_blank">Lithan</a>
demo</div>
</body>
</html>
```

script.js File

```
var default_content="";

$(document).ready(function(){

    checkURL();
    $('ul li a').click(function (e){
            checkURL(this.hash);
    });

    //filling in the default content
    default_content = $('#pageContent').html();


    setInterval("checkURL()",250);

});

var lasturl="";

function checkURL(hash)
{
    if(!hash) hash=window.location.hash;

    if(hash != lasturl)
    {
        lasturl=hash;
        // FIX - if we've used the history buttons to return to the homepage,
        // fill the pageContent with the default_content
        if(hash=="")
        $('#pageContent').html(default_content);

        else{
         if(hash=="#products")
            loadProducts();
         else
           loadPage(hash);
        }
    }
}


function loadPage(url)
{
    url=url.replace('#','');

    $('#loading').css('visibility','visible');

    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "load_page.jsp",
        data: 'page='+url,
        dataType: "html",
        success: function(msg){

            if(parseInt(msg)!=0)
            {
                $('#pageContent').html(msg);
                $('#loading').css('visibility','hidden');
            }
        }

    });

}

function loadProducts() {
  $('#loading').css('visibility','visible');
  var jsonURL = "products.json";
  $.getJSON(jsonURL, function (json)
  {
    var imgList= "<ul class=\"products\">";
    $.each(json.products, function () {
      imgList += '<li><img src= "' + this.imgPath + '"><h3>' + this.name + '</h3></li>';
    });
    imgList+='</ul>'
   $('#pageContent').html(imgList);
   $('#loading').css('visibility','hidden');
  });
}
```

.JSON File

```
{
"productDes": [{
        "title": "Mushrooms",
        "details": "A mushroom, or toadstool, is the fleshy, spore-bearing fruiting body of a fungus, typically produced above ground on soil or on its food source.",
        "price": "1kg = SGD20"

    },
    {

        "title": "Potato",
        "details": "The potato is a starchy, tuberous crop from the perennial nightshade Solanum tuberosum, native to the Americas. In many contexts, potato refers to the edible tuber, but it can also refer to the plant itself. Common or slang terms include tater, tattie and spud.",
        "price": "1kg = SGD7"

    },
    {

        "title": "Carrot",
        "details": "The carrot is a root vegetable, usually orange in colour, though purple, black, red, white, and yellow cultivars exist. Carrots are a domesticated form of the wild carrot, Daucus carota, native to Europe and southwestern Asia.",
        "price": "1kg = SGD4"

    },
    {

        "title": "Tomato",
        "details": "The tomato is the edible, often red, berry of the plant Solanum lycopersicum, commonly known as a tomato plant. The species originated in western South America. The Nahuatl word tomatl gave rise to the Spanish word tomate, from which the English word tomato derived.",
        "price": "1kg = SGD5"

    }
 ]
}
```

I want to change existing contents on my content area only while the navigation buttons and the whole page is not being refreshed whereas only the content area gets updated to the content of Title, Description, Price and an Image beside the contents.

Comment: I going to post an example in a few minutes hoe it helps =)

Comment: You were on the right track with ajax. You need to tell us specifically what issues you're having with the ajax in order to be helped. What have you already tried, and what about that failed?

Comment: Is there a way to post image over here? As I have some images that could tell what im trying to do.

Answer (score 0):

I dont know what kinda of html elements are you using when you talk abouut "navigation buttons and a content area for contents" but it does not really matters since all you want to do is load data into some html elements.

This example uses a formatUnicorn function with templates, ajax and your json file , the fucntion creates an html element per json element of your productDes array using a simple loop:

The HTML content:

```
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title></title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.4.0/css/bootstrap.min.css">
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.4.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.4.0/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
    <script type="text/template" id="listTemplate">
        <li ><a data-toggle="tab" href="#{title}">{title}</a></li>
    </script>
    <script type="text/template" id="divTemplate">
        <div id="{title}" class="tab-pane fade">
            <h3>{title}</h3>
            <p>{details}</p>
            <br>
            <p>Price: {price}</p>
        </div>
    </script>
    <div class="container">
        <h2>Navigation with Tabs</h2>
        <p>Example to fill json content in tabs</p>

        <ul class="nav nav-tabs" id="listOfItems">
            <li class="active"><a data-toggle="tab" href="#home">Home</a></li>
        </ul>

        <div class="tab-content" id="listOfDivs">
            <div id="home" class="tab-pane fade in active">
                <h3>HOME</h3>
                <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua.</p>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</body>
```

The script :

```
String.prototype.formatUnicorn =  function () {
    "use strict";
    var str = this.toString();
    if (arguments.length) {
        var t = typeof arguments[0];
        var key;
        var args = ("string" === t || "number" === t) ?
        Array.prototype.slice.call(arguments)
        : arguments[0];

        for (key in args) {
            str = str.replace(new RegExp("\\{" + key + "\\}", "gi"), (Array.isArray(args[key]) ? JSON.stringify(args[key]) : args[key]));
        }
    }
    return str;
};
// this function replaces the {} elements with the value of and array element that have the same key name
function _ajax(){
    return $.ajax({
        url: 'products.json',
        type: 'GET',
        dataType: 'JSON'
    })
}
//a simple ajax function to get the productDes array from the products.json file
//once you call the function and get the response with the deferred done you loop through the array
//and fill the template with the element that match the key, after that you append the element to your container
 _ajax().
 done((response)=>{
     let lisItemTemplate = $('#listTemplate').html(),
     divItemTemplate = $('#divTemplate').html();

     console.log(response);
    if (response.productDes.length > 0) {
        $.each(response.productDes,function(index, el) {
            var listItem = lisItemTemplate.formatUnicorn(el);
            var divItem = divItemTemplate.formatUnicorn(el);
            $('#listOfItems').append(listItem);
            $('#listOfDivs').append(divItem);
        });
    }
 })
```

Finally here is the snippet without ajax using only the products array:

```js
String.prototype.formatUnicorn = function() {
  "use strict";
  var str = this.toString();
  if (arguments.length) {
    var t = typeof arguments[0];
    var key;
    var args = ("string" === t || "number" === t) ?
      Array.prototype.slice.call(arguments) :
      arguments[0];

    for (key in args) {
      str = str.replace(new RegExp("\\{" + key + "\\}", "gi"), (Array.isArray(args[key]) ? JSON.stringify(args[key]) : args[key]));
    }
  }
  return str;
};

let products = {
  "productDes": [{
      "title": "Mushrooms",
      "details": "A mushroom, or toadstool, is the fleshy, spore-bearing fruiting body of a fungus, typically produced above ground on soil or on its food source.",
      "price": "1kg = SGD20"

    },
    {

      "title": "Potato",
      "details": "The potato is a starchy, tuberous crop from the perennial nightshade Solanum tuberosum, native to the Americas. In many contexts, potato refers to the edible tuber, but it can also refer to the plant itself. Common or slang terms include tater, tattie and spud.",
      "price": "1kg = SGD7"

    },
    {

      "title": "Carrot",
      "details": "The carrot is a root vegetable, usually orange in colour, though purple, black, red, white, and yellow cultivars exist. Carrots are a domesticated form of the wild carrot, Daucus carota, native to Europe and southwestern Asia.",
      "price": "1kg = SGD4"

    },
    {

      "title": "Tomato",
      "details": "The tomato is the edible, often red, berry of the plant Solanum lycopersicum, commonly known as a tomato plant. The species originated in western South America. The Nahuatl word tomatl gave rise to the Spanish word tomate, from which the English word tomato derived.",
      "price": "1kg = SGD5"

    }
  ]
};

let lisItemTemplate = $('#listTemplate').html(),
  divItemTemplate = $('#divTemplate').html();

if (products.productDes.length > 0) {
  $.each(products.productDes, function(index, el) {
    var listItem = lisItemTemplate.formatUnicorn(el);
    var divItem = divItemTemplate.formatUnicorn(el);
    $('#listOfItems').append(listItem);
    $('#listOfDivs').append(divItem);
  });
}
```

```html
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.4.0/css/bootstrap.min.css">
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.4.0/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>


<body>
  <script type="text/template" id="listTemplate">
    <li><a data-toggle="tab" href="#{title}">{title}</a></li>
  </script>
  <script type="text/template" id="divTemplate">
    <div id="{title}" class="tab-pane fade">
      <h3>{title}</h3>
      <p>{details}</p>
      <br>
      <p>Price: {price}</p>
    </div>
  </script>
  <div class="container">
    <h2>Navigation with Tabs</h2>
    <p>Example to fill json content in tabs</p>

    <ul class="nav nav-tabs" id="listOfItems">
      <li class="active"><a data-toggle="tab" href="#home">Home</a></li>
    </ul>

    <div class="tab-content" id="listOfDivs">
      <div id="home" class="tab-pane fade in active">
        <h3>HOME</h3>
        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua.</p>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</body>
```

Hope it helps

Comment: Yes this is what I was trying to figure out. But is it possible to do it on the new codes I added ?

Comment: @NewToThisOutblast Sure just replace the content of the div insteand of append mutliple divs